# ¿Como renombrar una tabla mysql en php?

Tags: php, mysql

lo que quiero es renombrar una tabla desde php. He intentado con esto:

```
mysql_query("RENAME TABLE ". $tablaNom ." TO `.$nombre.`") or die(mysql_error());
```

La linea anterior me renombra la tabla pero me pone un "." en el nombre y cuando quiero hacer un select me dice que la tabla no existe.

De igual forma he tratado usando la siguiente linea:

```
mysql_query("RENAME TABLE ". $tablaNom ." TO `".$nombre."`") or die(mysql_error());
```

Pero me dice lo siguiente: "Incorrect table name".

Ojala puedan ayudarme, y de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Vas por buen camino, te hacía falta definir bien las comillas de retroceso: ``

```
mysql_query( "RENAME TABLE `" . $tablaNom . "` TO `" . $nombre. "`" ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hola @fredyfx agradesco tu respuesta, ya puse las comillas que me indicaste en mi código y aun así me dice que el nombre es incorrecto, no se que otra cosa podría ser.

Comment: de nada @A.Monreal, vamos por partes como dice Jack, primero, lanza un echo a todo lo que anda dentro del mysql_query para ver si es exactamente lo que esperas o hay algo raro al capturar el nombre de la tabla. Al mismo tiempo, revisa si la tabla contiene el mismo nombre. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho batallar logre que funcionara, solo que no entendí el porque funciono. Lo que hice fue remover las comillas, los puntos y las comillas de retroceso de la segunda variable; es decir la que contiene el nuevo nombre de la tabla.

```
mysql_query( "RENAME TABLE `" . $tablaNom . "` TO  $nombre " ) or die(mysql_error());
```

De todas formas gracias y espero esta respuesta les sea de ayuda a otras personas.

Saludos